# Any ideas as to why my Desktop and Multitasking backgrounds are rendering funny?

Tags: release-loki, display, nvidia, macintosh

Apologies if this is more appropriate for the subreddit, but my question felt supportish.

Anyway, I just stumbled across elementary (mac user since I was like 7) and decided to give it a shot last night.

Really liking it so far, but I woke up this morning to a noisy desktop background image:

[image: Noisy desktop bg]

I toggled the desktop image, which fixed the bg image besides a few pixels in each corner and the multitasking background:

[image: Screenshot: errors in corner pixels]
[image: Screenshot: error in multitasking background]

Basic environment info:

- elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
- Dual booting on a 2012 iMac
- Quad-Core Intel Core i7-3770S CPU @ 3.10GHz
- NVIDIA Corporation
  GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition] (rev a1)
- I'm using the
  nvidia-384 driver available through AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem comes to me every time when my computer returns from suspend.

I cannot say that it is a nice solution, but I found that there's no problem if I switch to the Intel GPU(Power Saving Mode) from the NVIDIA X Server Settings app. [image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same, NVIDEA related issue as https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8952/artifacts-in-background. Could you copy your answer to there?